# Enlarging buttons for different screen sizes using constraints

Tags: ios, uibutton, interface-builder

still struggling with this one. I am tying to create a kind of on screen keyboard and have a layout of UIButtons like so:

[image]

I want to buttons to scale up as the screen does to make it more comfortable for larger devices e.g.:

[image]

Some rows will have an odd number of buttons and some will have an even number. I am putting each row of buttons inside separate holder views. Not totally clear how I should set up the constraints on the holder view. Should I pin the holder to the leading and trailing superview edges, and constrain the aspect ratio?

For the top row I have tried adding separators between the buttons. I then tried this:

```
Button3.width = Button3.height (aspect ratio)

Button3.width = HolderView.superview.width * (1/5) - 10

Button3.trailing to Spacer, Button4.leading to Spacer

Button3 bottom/top constraints to superview
```

Can't seem to get any blue lines though. Any instructions on how to proceed with this would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks

Comment: how large shall the buttons in the rows with less buttons be? let's say you have 7 buttons in row 1 (like in your picture) and only 4 buttons in row 2. how do you want to align them and how large should they be?

Comment: I want the initial size to be 35*35 but grow as the screen gets larger, i.e. bigger for iPhone 6 an 6+. The first row with odd buttons can be centred working from the middle button. The second row centred working from the middle spacer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a quick look at my demo project: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/vlozb5uxjor0ryd/AACOio_P6gorNvsSATxtdqP4a?dl=0. i have some plans now and try to explain it later... ;)

Comment: EXACTLY what I'm looking for! Please explain it later when you have the time.

Comment: glad to hear :) maybe you can mark my answer as correct. as i said i'll edit it and add a small explanation later to make things clear! thx!

Comment: My main issue is the two different rows. I have it working for the each row independently, but because the rows are different widths (i.e. there is one less button) the buttons on the top row are a different size to the bottom ones.

Comment: you simply have to select ALL buttons (no matter in what row they are) and create **equal widths** and **equal height** constraints.

Comment: I'm trying that and getting Unable to satisfy all constraints and one of my buttons is the wrong size. My constraints are like so:
1.) 
First select container 1, pin bottom, trailing and leading. Select all buttons in container 1, pin top, bottom, leading, trailing and aspect ratio.
2.) 
Select container 2, pin bottom, leading and trailing. Select all buttons in container 2, pin top, bottom, leading, trailing and aspect ratio.
3.)
Select all buttons in container 1 and container 2. Pin equal width and equal height.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/e8u2bccvkywoorg/buttons.zip?dl=0 Could u take a look?

Comment: ok. change the following constraints for container 2: leading and trailing space to superview GREATER THAN the default value. for the left most button in container 2 change the leading space to superview constant to 0. for the right most button in container 2 change the trailing space to superview constant to 0. for container 2 add an ALIGN CENTER X TO SUPERVIEW constraint.

Comment: Leave everything exactly as I have in the link above and then add these changes?

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/21jreao/9 no constraint complaints but the top row isn't completely centred now..

Comment: could you upload your updated project to dropbox again? then i can take a look.

Comment: whatever. :) glad i could help!